# Springboot-JPA not saving the data in the database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Springboot-JPA not inserting the data in the database when I deploy it on wildfly but inserts data in DB when executing the same code from STS.

#1 application.properties

```
spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.main.allow-circular-references:true
spring.main.web-environment=false
```

#2 Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@EnableWebMvc
public class BlogController {
    @Autowired
    BlogService blogService;
    // create blog entry 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/writeblog", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody Blog createBlog(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @ModelAttribute Blog blogContent)
            throws IOException {
        return blogService.saveBlogContent(file, blogContent);
    }
}
```

#3 Service

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class BlogService {
    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    private BlogRepository blogRepository;

    public Blog saveBlogContent(MultipartFile file, Blog blogContent) throws IOException {
        String blogImgURl = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/api/blogimage/").toUriString();
        
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(millis);
        blogContent.setImage(file.getBytes());
        
        blogContent.setPublishDate(date);
        blogContent.setBlogImageUrl(blogImgURl);
        Blog blog = blogRepository.saveAndFlush(blogContent);
        return blog;
    }
}
```

#4 Repository

```
@Repository
public interface BlogRepository extends JpaRepository<Blog, Long>{

    Blog findByBlogId(Long blogId);
}
```

#5 I am getting the object with autogenerated ID as I have used below code in model: (@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) private long blogId; Returning:

```
{ "blogId": 10, 
"employeeId": 202, 
"blogTitle": "blog Title TEST-55", 
"blogContent": "blog CONTENT TESTING-555", 
"image": "" 
}
```

When I execute the code from STS IDE then it's saving the value in the database but when I deploy the **war file** on the **wildfly** server then
it is not saving it in **database**.

**Please guide me why the same code is behaving differently or am I missing something?**

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, I am getting the object with autogenerated ID as I have used below code in model:
(@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long blogId;

Returning:
{
    "blogId": 10,
    "employeeId": 20180362,
    "blogTitle": "blog Title TEST-55",
    "blogContent": "blog CONTENT TESTING-555",
    "image": ""
}

This should be saved in DB.

Comment: Maybe your transaction is not committed for some reason or it's rolled back?

You can try to enable hibernate's autcommit property temporarily.

You can also try to enable showing SQL queries (e.g. set `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` as the simplest way to do this).

And you can also enable DEBUG logs globally (or at least in spring and hibernate) and check them for any useful information.
Yet another possibility is that some dependency that is expected to be provided is not provided by Wildfly but then you should get some errors so I doubt it's a reaosn.

Comment: @Pawel It's not allowing me to set autcommit property true as I am using Blob in the model for saving images.
And I have done this "spring.jpa.show-sql=true" and the below query gets executed when I tried to save and I think it's correct but still not saving 
data into the DB
Hibernate: insert into blogs (blog_content, blog_image_url, blog_title, employee_id, blog_image, is_published, is_reviewed, likes, date) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Answer (score 0):

Please add Main class @EnableJpaRepositories

Comment: Added @EnableJpaRepositories but no luck.

Comment: using save dont saveAndFlush

Comment: Still not saving the data.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, In my case I modified the below and it's working now:

1. I removed all the BLOB data type.
2. I removed the concept of Join as well.
   These two were creating problem.